# Tag restrictions trigger robot detection

Tags: support, tags

When I try to post, especially on a new Stack Overflow off-shoot account where I have little reputation, it's very hard to satisfy the tag restrictions.

- I often don't know which tags apply to my post.
- I have to supply a few tags.
- But the tags have to be already in the system.
- And the tags have to be relevant.
- And I can't make new tags with little reputation.

So how am I supposed to post a question on XYZ topic if in everyone agrees that XYZ is relevant to a specific Stack Overflow off-shoot, but the tags just haven't been created yet?

Due to these conflicts, as I try to submit tags that will satisfy the tag restrictions, but more importantly, the human readers, Stack Overflow's robot detection goes haywire. It suddenly requests captchas for every. little. tag. change. I'm **not** a robot, my actions are forced to look rote because I basically have to brute-force the tag system to get anything slightly obscure posted.

E.g., A new programming language BubbaGump comes out, and you have trouble with the syntax. So you write up a Stack Overflow post, but you're a new user and there's no bubbagump tag yet. What do?

Comment: What's the proposal in this question - relax the tag restrictions for users with less points or something else?

Comment: @JW8, Yes. Relax tag restrictions, and relax bot detection. When real bots spam, they don't do it by reediting a post at human speed. They do it by posting new questions and comments from the same IP address faster than a human can type.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the question without the new (not existing) tag. Add other relevant tags. Normaly a question fits to more than one tag.
2. A new user could add a comment, or note in the question, that an other user with higher reputation should create the new tag and retag the question.
3. With 15 reputation you can `flag` the question to a moderator to get direct attention and add the request for a tag in the custom text.

Answer (score 0):

But users are miss using and newbies are not getting opportunity to really get help from the community. I think newbies should be removed with tag restrictions.

Infact it can be automated by sending a note to moderators to review and approve the tags added  just like community wiki. Tags should have a similar feature for moderators renewing it and then making them available for use.